# Fedora says my disk is full, but it isnt

Tags: fedora, disk-space

What is happening? I got a fancy ultrabook to work. It has one of those hard drives that has 500gb of hard disk and 20gb of solid state drive.

I've mounted the main OS partitions on the solid state. /, /root and the swap partition

The /home is on the hard disk but fedora is dumb and is not understanding this and tells me my disk is full.

Is there a way of telling that to Fedora 'Hey, don't count home space, because it's in a different hard drive' ?

- sdb = solid state
- sda = hard disk

THis is my `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3        20G   20G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  1.2M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  3.9M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G   36K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb2       477M   89M  359M  20% /boot
/dev/sdb1       200M  9.4M  191M   5% /boot/efi  
/dev/sda6       401G   36G  345G  10% /home   36G!!!
```

Comment: Could quotas be the issue?

Comment: How so? When I run disk analyser, the size of the  main partition changes every time. I have a windows vm that is taking 13GB. Ran diskanalyzer and it said / had 50GB, duplicated the vm, ran disk analyzer and / had 63GB on it's size... I'm prety sure it's some kind of logic problem.
But i'm all ears, tell me what you think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't count `/home` as part of `/`; it's smart enough to not do so. You really are out of space on `/`.